# Send a copy to the sender of the contact form

Tags: php, email, contact-form

My contact form works fine, but I can't get it to send a copy of the email to the sender. Here's my code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="De: $name \n Mensaje: $message";
$recipient = "contacto@mydomain.cl";
$subject = "Mensaje desde el sitio web";
$header = "From: $email \r\n";
$header .= "Cc: $email" . "\r\n";


mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $header) or die("Error!");
echo "Tu consulta fue recibida, pronto nos comunicaremos contigo";
```

As you can see, I'm adding the `$email`, which is the mail the sender inputs, as a cc to the `$header`, but it's not working. Actually like this the mail is not even sent to the recipient, so I guess it must be some syntax error, that I can't seem to find. I copied the code directly from another answer on the site, but changed the string value to `$email`. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you running this? If the mail doesn't even reach the `$recipient` then it might be that there simply is no mail server available to send the mail?

Comment: I'm running it on the actual server. It worked fine before I added the line to attempt to CC to the sender.

Comment: Does it work again when you remove the CC part now?

Comment: Yes, when I remove that it works fine.

Comment: Oh I think I see it now. `$header = "From: $email \r\n";
$header .= "Cc: $email" . "\r\n";` Your CC line has the `" . "` part before `\r\n`. Which probably causes it to parse wrong (missing space). Just use `$header .= "Cc: $email \r\n";` and it should be fine.